# Instance method '-decrytedWithKey' not found (return defaults tyoe to 'id')

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've got some encrypted data and I wanna decrypt it once the app is launched. I do it with this code:

```
NSMutableData *FR2ENData=[NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfFile:FR2ENFilePath];
        FR2ENData=[FR2ENData decryptedWithKey:@"XXXXXXXX"];
        NSString * FR2ENString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[FR2ENData bytes]];
        NSArray *FR2EN0=[FR2ENString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

And I've got this caution message:

Instance method '-decrytedWithKey' not found (return defaults tyoe to 'id')

How can I clean it?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: c# ???? I guess this is Objective-c.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Yesterday I saw an Objective-C question tagged C++... Xcode is *somewhat* understandable, but C# and C++? Really?

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a *category header* for the `decryptedWithKey:` method of `NSData`. It looks like you are using an extension category [defined by the user Karl in the third post on this page](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6982) (I copied a header below):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSData (AES256)
- (NSData*) encryptedWithKey:(NSData*) key;
- (NSData*) decryptedWithKey:(NSData*) key;
@end
```

Your code needs to import this header in order to avoid the compilation error. You also need to add the implementation to your project, either as a source or as a library, in order to avoid a linking error.